# PHP delete query does not send the id

Tags: php, mysql

I tried to delete data out of PHPMyAdmin tables using PDO and it is not working. My connection is established. When I click on the delete button in the URL it would not pass in the ID. Any ideas how I can get it to work?

Here is the form:

```
<?php include_once 'admin/includes/helpers.inc.php';?>
<?php include 'index.php' ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <title>List of Jokes</title>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href ="/comp1321_database/jokes/form.html.php/">Add your own joke</a></p>     
<p>Here are all the jokes in the database</p>
<!-- into a table -->
        <table border="1">
        <?php foreach ($jokes as $joke): ?>
            
             <form action="?deletejoke" method="POST">  
             <tr>
             <td><?php html($joke['joketext']);?></td>

             <td><?php $display_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($joke['jokedate']));
             html($display_date); ?>
         </td>
         <td><img height="100px" src="../images/<?php html($joke['image']);?>" /></td>

             <td><a href=" mailto:<?php html($joke['email']);?>">
               
             <?php html($joke['name']);?></a></td>          

            </td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $joke['joke_id'];
            ?>">

            <input type="submit" value="Delete"></td>
        </tr>
     </form> 
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
   <?php include 'admin/includes/footer.inc.html.php';?>   
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my delete block:

```
if (isset($_POST['deletejoke'])) {
    try
{
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM joke WHERE joke_id = :id';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':id', $_POST['id']);
    $s->execute();

} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error ='Error deleting joke' . $e->getMessage();
    include 'error.html.pp';
    exit();
}
header('Location: .');
exit();
}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: Instead of `if (isset($_POST['deletejoke']))` try `if (isset($_POST['id']))`

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`deletejoke` is the name of the form which is not passed through to `$_POST`.

This line:

```php
if (isset($_POST['deletejoke']))
```

Should be

```php
if (isset($_POST['id']))
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all you got an error in your code in your `catch`:

```
`include 'error.html.pp';`
```

should probably be:

```
include 'error.html.php';
```

Second thing is that you are not passing any value in `$_POST['deletejoke']`, as it is being sent as `$_GET` if being sent at all when it has no value (depends of the browser)...

So basically change this:

```
<form action="?deletejoke" method="POST">
```

to this:

```
<form action="?deletejoke=1" method="POST">
```

And...

```
if (isset($_POST['deletejoke'])) {
```

to:

```
if (isset($_GET['deletejoke'])) {
```

Comment: There is POST value, in `$_POST['id']`

Comment: but he checks `deletejoke` that is being declared in `form` action as `get` param, the rest of the code is fine, just `if` doesn't happen.

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $joke['joke_id']; ?>">`

Comment: Yep, check Dazed comment and answer

Comment: Programming is great because the same thing can be accomplished different ways. This is a clear case of that.

Comment: @dazed-and-confused that's true, your answer is correct, just not related to the code given... might be even better and faster than mine, if there would be no other actions implemented like `?editjoke`

Comment: @FlashThunder ahhhhhhhhh. NOOOOW I get what you're going after. My answer just solves this, right here, right now, quick and dirty. Yours "might be" taking into account the direction of what OP is going for.

Comment: Just spent a minute trying this out because I didn't fully get the `?deletejoke=1` as the action... Brain fart that it submits to itself with that added as the query string. I personally do not like that way but as I just said, tmtowtdi.

Comment: yeah I am pretty underestimated by trying to find a solution matched to the question every time... every time, even when I answered first and valid, my answer is not accepted, I am pretty sick of that, I just don't assume that the OP is a total newbie in the subject and trying to think about the code as a bigger thing; that is why I stopped to help as much on SO at some point